# Set breaks between values in continuous axis of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can we set the breaks of continous axis every 2 numbers if we have a very big range of values in an axis and cannot set it manually?

```
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()
p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2, 4, 6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `?scale_x_continuous` help page, `breaks` can be (among other options)

> A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output

The `scales` package offers `breaks_width()` for exactly this purpose:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(2))
```

Here's an anonymous function going from the (floored) min to the (ceilinged) max by 2:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = \(x) seq(floor(x[1]), ceiling(x[2]), by = 2))
```

Alternately you could still use `seq` for finer control, more customizable, less generalizable:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2, 6, by = 2))
```

Comment: Another option would be to use `scales::breaks_width()` like `scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(2))`