# How to display all values on X and Y axes in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 I want to display

(1) all the values in x-axis `1`,`2`,`....`,`15`

(2) raw number instead of the scientific notation

[image]

Below is my code

```
cycle_time <- 1:15
volume <- c(109.12,381.11,812.31,1109,4439.32, 12148.29,32514.32,82231.24,183348.44,329472.36,462381.96,541111.67,
            576516.09, 590450.40,595642.83)

dfx <- data.frame(as.factor(cycle_time),volume)

p1<- ggplot(dfx, aes(cycle_time,volume)) + geom_line()
p1
```

Please share your full code

Thanx in advance

Comment: Do these two questions/answers solve your problem? [How to disable scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation) and [Set breaks between values in continuous axis of ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978496/set-breaks-between-values-in-continuous-axis-of-ggplot)

Comment: @ jared_mamrot Thanks, this fixes the `Y` axis. Any suggestion for `X` axis? I want to display all the values in `cycle_time`  - `1`,`2`,.......`15`.

Comment: for the x-axis `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = cycle_time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
cycle_time <- 1:15
volume <- c(109.12,381.11,812.31,1109,4439.32, 12148.29,32514.32,82231.24,183348.44,329472.36,462381.96,541111.67,
            576516.09, 590450.40,595642.83)

dfx <- data.frame(cycle_time,volume)

p1<- ggplot(dfx, aes(cycle_time,volume)) + geom_line()
p1 +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,15,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>